# send message to specific client using soocket.io while socket id changes rapidly

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm running a chat server using node.js and socket and want to send message to specific client.I use socket.id to send the message to the defined user,like this:

```
io.sockets.in(user socket.id).emit('message',message)
```

but there is a problem:
user remains connect but socket id changes rapidly(About once per second) so i can not use socket.id.I tried socket.join(user email) to use user email instead of socket id but after socket id changes it does not work any more.
what's the best way to solve this?session-id?If yes,how?chat application for clients runs on android device.
This is my code:

```
io.on("connection", function(socket) {

socket.on("login", function(useremail) {
 socket.join(useremail);
});

//Here i want to send message to specific user
socket.on('messagedetection', (senderNickname,messageContent,targetuser) => {

    //create a message object 
   let  message = {"message":messageContent, "senderNickname":senderNickname}

   //targetuser is the email of target user,joined to the socket in login 
   io.sockets.in(targetuser).emit('message',message)
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
console.log( ' user has left ')
socket.broadcast.emit("userdisconnect"," user has left ") });
```

Comment: That doesn't right at all, you'll need to provide more details as to why sockets are disconnecting / reconnecting at such a high rate.

Comment: @James Actually i don't know why it happens.because I don't have this problem on local host.

Comment: The problem to fix is the rapidly disconnecting/reconnecting clients.  That is a clear sign that something in the configuration is not correct.  It could be that network infrastructure is not properly configured to allow long lasting socket.io connections.  Or, if your system is clustered, it could be caused by non-sticky load balancing.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes. That was the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer since it was indeed the issue:

The problem to fix is the rapidly disconnecting/reconnecting clients. That is a clear sign that something in the configuration is not correct.

It could be that network infrastructure is not properly configured to allow long lasting socket.io/webSocket connections. Or, if your system is clustered, it could be caused by non-sticky load balancing.

So, each time the connection is shut-down by the network infrastructure, the client-side socket.io library tries to reconnect creating a new ID for the new connection.